# Powershell Regex vs. "other" Regex, what's different?

Tags: regex, powershell

I've got a powershell script to match the following regex:

```
---\n(0[1-9]|1[0-2][\/](0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[\/]\d{2}[\s\S]+?)-----
```

The string to match from is the following logfile snippet:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
10/26/16 11:41:26 - Process(15925376.4) User(mqm) Program(amqzmuc0)
                    Host(aixmq1) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(ecs.queue.manager)
                    AMQ6287: WebSphere MQ V8.0.0.4 (p800-004-151017).

EXPLANATION: WebSphere MQ system information:  Host Info         :-
AIX 7.1 (MQ AIX 64-bit)  Installation      :- /usr/mqm (Installation1)
Version           :- 8.0.0.4 (p800-004-151017) ACTION: None.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
10/26/16 11:41:26 - Process(15925376.4) User(mqm) Program(amqzmuc0)
                    Host(aixmq1) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(ecs.queue.manager)
                    AMQ6287: WebSphere MQ V8.0.0.4 (p800-004-151017).

EXPLANATION:FFF WebSphere MQ system information:  Host Info         :-
AIX 7.1 (MQ AIX 64-bit)  Installation      :- /usr/mqm (Installation1)
Version           :- 8.0.0.4 (p800-004-151017) ACTION: None.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Using this regex in perl and on regexr.com, it perfectly matches two sections from that logfile snippet.

Now i've implemented that same regex in powershell and it won't return any matches unless i remove the minuses preceding the \n. If i replace those minuses by a matching group that only contains minus, it will work aswell.

For the sake of consistency and understanding what is going on , i need to understand why the matching behavior is so different in powershell. Why won't it match as soon as there are minuses at the beginning?

The following .NET regex tester shows the same behavior as in powershell:

http://regexstorm.net/tester

Could someone please explain to me why the matching behavior is that different in powershell compared to perl/regexr.com?

This is the snippet of powershell code i'm currently using to match that regex:

```
$matches = ([regex]::matches($sInput, "---\n(0[1-9]|1[0-2][\/](0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[\/]\d{2}[\s\S]+?)\n-") | %{$_.value});
```

Comment: May I ask what the point of the first alternation of your regex is `0[1-9]`? The only thing it does, is making it match a line preceded by a *hyphen line*, containing the number `01` to `09`, directly followed by another *hyphen line*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, line endings are (usually) `CRLF` (two characters, carriage return then linefeed), whereas on unix-based operating systems (basically anything but Windows) it's just a linefeed `LF`. The escape sequence `\n` refers to LF. To match CR use `\r`.

So what I think is happening is that if your input contains `CRLF`, then `-\n` will not match it. But `\n` would because it skips the preceding `CR`.

The websites you're using to test it may convert the line endings, or not properly preserve them, and therefore match, while the .Net tester may do the opposite.

For reference, whenever I need to match line endings in regex, I use `\r?\n` (an optional `CR` followed by a `LF`), so that I can catch both types of line endings.

So in your example, you should be able to change the beginning of your regex from `---\n` to `---\r?\n` and have it work, if I am correct about your specific issue.

Comment: Or as in the [regex101 example here](https://regex101.com/r/HZXEzl/1), simply put `\s*` and you should be safe for any combinations.

Comment: @ClasG I would say `\s+` since `\s*` will "match" nothing as well, but yes that would catch both types of line endings because it will catch all whitespace. That's not always what you want though; if you know you want to catch line endings only, then I strongly recommend `\r?\n`. If you want to match any whitespace whatsoever, then definitely use the `\s` class.